# Not able to send flags when using RVM wrapper

Tags: ruby, unix, rvm

I'm trying to use crontab with my RVM setup (creating a backup using [backup gem](http://meskyanichi.github.io/backup/v4/)).

My crontab entry runs the following command several times a day:

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/wrappers/backup -t app
```

However, for some misterious reason, the `-t` flag is beeing changed to `_t` (dash turns to underscore so also `--trigger` changes to `__trigger`). In cause of that, i'm not able to use that bin correctly. Error message says:

> Could not find command "_t"

Please note that using `backup -t app` works fine, just using a wrapper fails.

Is there any reason behing such behavior? What can i do to run a wrapper with non-underscored flags? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you run the wrapper *not* via cron, does the wrapper succeed?

Comment: No. Dashes are also changed to underscores.

Comment: Ok, then it sounds like cron isn't the issue, so I suggest you edit your post to remove the cron info because it's a red herring.

Comment: Never put a script in Crontab before at least it works correctly from the command line. You say the wrapper fails, so : check the wrapper.